# How does postgres not to escape when I copy csv to it?

Tags: postgresql

I want to copy a csv to postgres. And some value is string like this `"{\"foo\": 123}"`

If I use the COPY in the postgres directly, it will escape the string. when I select from postgres, it will become "{foo: 123}", but it's hard for me to handle, so how to not to escape the `"`. That is to say, I hope I can get the origin string `"{\"foo\": 123}"` when I select it from postgres

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE meuk
        ( bagger varchar
        );
COPY meuk(bagger) FROM stdin WITH CSV QUOTE '"' ESCAPE E'\\' ;
"{\"foo\": 123}"
\.

SELECT * from meuk;
```

Result:

```
CREATE TABLE
    bagger    
--------------
 {"foo": 123}
(1 row)
```